# How to shorten filename displayed in DSpace

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, dspace

I would like to shorten the file name that is being displayed in the simple item view.

If I have a very long file name, this is displayed in the simple item record:

[image: simple-view]

This example file name is shortened if you view the full item record:

[image: full-record-view]

But if you edit this item and click the **Item Bitstreams** tab, the file name is being displayed like this:

[image]

My goal is to apply what is being displayed in the edit bitstream (the 3rd picture) to the simple and full item view. I don't know where this transformation is being generated. I looked at administrative.xsl and I can't find anything on the shortening of the file name. Please advice on how to achieve this or where to look for this transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite of the file name in the "Item Bitstreams" tab is done in Java code, not in the XSL. It's here: [EditItemBitstreamsForm.java](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/administrative/item/EditItemBitstreamsForm.java#L147).

Your item page screenshot looks like you're working in XMLUI / Mirage 2, is that right? Your best bet is to use the `shortenString` method in `org.dspace.app.xmlui.utils.XSLUtils` ([code](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/utils/XSLUtils.java#L22)). Actually maybe you aren't using Mirage 2 because Mirage 2 does just that, see [item-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/utils/XSLUtils.java#L22):

```
<xsl:value-of select="util:shortenString(mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:title, 30, 5)"/>
```

Comment: The screenshot is from Mirage 2. The `util:shortenString` if I'm not wrong is used in the full item record view (just like in the 2nd screenshot)? I want to insert an ellipsis in the middle of the string and not at the end ie `this is very lo ... for a file name.pdf`. Thanks for pointing me to `EditItemBitstreamsForm.java`, but I don't know how to port that code in xslt.

Comment: Never mind Andrea, I think I figured it out. Thanks again. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72625/schweerelos) for the answer. Here's my code and how I used it.

I created a new method `shortenFileName` in `org.dspace.app.xmlui.utils.XSLUtils`

```
    public static String shortenFileName(String string, String middle, int targetLength) {
        targetLength = Math.abs(targetLength);

        if (string != null && string.length() > targetLength) {
            // If the file name is too long then shorten it so that it will display nicely.
            return StringUtils.abbreviateMiddle(string, middle, targetLength);
        }
        else
            return string;
    }
```

and then used it in `item-view.xsl` like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="util:shortenFileName(mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:title, ' &#8230; ', 20)" />
```

The **file name** now looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry, yes you did write that you want to shorten it in the middle, I missed that. Your solution looks great!