# How to override the generation of RSS feeds in DSpace?

Tags: rss, xslt-1.0, dspace

This is somewhat related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32263468/1919069). I was asked to modify the results of the RSS feeds such that the list will be the same as when you view the `/browse?type=dateissued` in descending order. I can't find where the resulting list of the RSS feeds are generated. Or is this even doable?

I am using **DSpace version 5.3 Mirage 2 Theme**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `recent.submissions.sort-option` in [dspace.cfg](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L1312) which claims to work for feeds as well:

```
# the sort option name (from webui.itemlist.sort-option above) to use for
# displaying recent submissions.  (this
# is used by the Recent Submissions system and any other time based
# browse query such as FeedServlet)
recent.submissions.sort-option = dateaccessioned
```

[Looks like](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/cocoon/DSpaceFeedGenerator.java#L257) that's used in XMLUI as well, so you may be able to achieve what you describe by setting this option to `dateissued`.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I overlooked that option in `dspace.cfg` and thought that those settings were overwritten by discovery. Anyways, I changed my `recent.submissions.sort-option = dateissued`. One thing I've noticed is that **only RSS 1.0 and Atom feeds** are respecting that sort option. RSS 2.0 is still displaying the default. I'm not sure if this is cached. Any advice?

Comment: Try clearing the Cocoon cache, I agree that this sounds like a caching issue. https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/TechnicalFAQ#TechnicalFAQ-ClearingCocoon%28XMLUI%29cache

Comment: You're right Andrea, clearing the cache and doing a hard reload in the browser did the trick! Also, thanks for the anwers. I am so glad that this only require changing values in `dspace.cfg` and does not involved modifying java and xslt source code. :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got there -- and yeah it must have been a nice surprise for you that for once something was so easy ;)